# Base64 Decoding in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, base64, decode

I am working with the following script that reads a csv file and decodes it. When I run it, I receive an Incorrect Padding error. When I take an individual entry and perform a `str.decode('base64')`, I get an appropriate result (no error). What could be the problem?  Could some entries be corrupt and it's throwing the whole process off?

```
def get_sigpair_from_csv(csv_in, start=0, skip_to_tx=None, want_tx=[]):
    want_tx=set(want_tx)
    skip_entries = True
    with open(csv_in,'r') as f:
        for nr,line in enumerate(f):
            if nr<start:
                if nr%100000==0:
                    print "skip",nr,f.tell()
                continue
            if nr % 10000000 == 0:
                print "10m", nr
            try:
                # read data
                cols = line.split(";",1)
                tx = cols[0].strip()

                if skip_to_tx and tx==skip_to_tx:
                    skip_entries=False
                    # skip this entry - already in db
                    continue
                if skip_to_tx and skip_entries:
                    print "skiptx",nr, tx
                    continue
                if want_tx and tx not in want_tx:
                    continue

                scriptsig = cols[1].decode("base64")
                sig = scriptsig_to_ecdsa_sig(scriptsig)
                sig['tx'] = tx
                sig['nr'] = nr
                yield sig
            except ValueError, ve:
                #print tx,repr(ve)
                pass
            except Exception, e:
                print tx, repr(e)
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
879b068c75492e9d860763e843212d7aed2fb81ad3ee24592b48cdf5df624dcd Error('Incorrect padding',)
```

However, when I do:

```
x = '879b068c75492e9d860763e843212d7aed2fb81ad3ee24592b48cdf5df624dcd'
x.decode('base64')
```

It works

Comment: Python has builtin module called `base64` https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html. You can simply use this module to encode `base64.encodestring("some string")` and `base64.decodestring("some base64 encoded string")` for encoding and decoding using base64

Comment: Unfortunately replacing cols[1].decode('base64') with the base64.decodestring() yields the same error

Comment: Base64 needs to be padded to even multiples of four characters. Show us the entry which fails. Maybe it's not base64 at all?

Comment: Thanks for the sample. This looks like a hex digit, not base64. (The base64 repertoire includes all these characters, but also many more.)

Comment: I'm guessing you left a newline at the end. Removing it will fix the immediate decoding error, but it's still garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @tripleee what do you mean by newline?

Comment: Seriously? [Newline.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)